# How to connect cloud_firestore to flutter windows app?

Tags: flutter, windows, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Support for windows has been added to [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) since `4.10.0` but I'm not able to find any documentation for the same.

When I use the code below

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options:  
  FirebaseOptions( apiKey: ".........", 
  appId: "......web:........", 
  messagingSenderId: ".........", 
  projectId:"............",  
  ));
```

I get the following error:

```
 \windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\cloud_firestore\windows\cloud_firestore_plugin.cpp(26,10): 
 error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'firebase/firestore/filter.h': 
 No such file or directory [path\build\windows\x64\plugins\cloud_firestore\cloud_firestore_plugin.vcxproj]
 Error: Build process failed
```

When I try using the older cloud_firestore versions, the exe file is build successfully and firebase_auth works fine.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You can take a look a the example on Github: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/example

Comment: @pcba-dev I'm getting the same error even on the example app. What can be the reason?

Comment: I do not have a Windows machine to test it, sorry. I was only sharing the link to the example to see if it could help you